# Can access Twitter with one specific user account?

Tags: ios, twitter

I am going to create an app which introduces retail stores. I want to add each store's twitter account programmatically to have read-only access. All twitter questions are talking about access via setting app in device. Is it possible to access twitter not via accounts stored in device?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do a couple of things.

1. If each store has a separate account, then each store account has to authorize your application to access it's account.
2. Once that is done, your application will need to retrieve and store the necessary OAuth tokens for each store.
3. Finally, your application will need to authenticate with the correct store's tokens when it wants to access Twitter as that store.